# How do I use an interrupt to reset my program or go back to main during a function call

Tags: c, microcontroller, 8051

I've tried everything, and I am aware of the (void (code *)(void)) 0) ();, but as you know if you use it doesn't clear back the interrupts and you can't use it again. 
What is a workaround, and I have to use an external interrupt based on my HW. I've researched countless hours and looked through several of my books. I'm starting to believe it may not be possible? 
Code:

```
#include <reg51.h>
void delay();
int i,a;
sbit btn=P3^2;
sbit sw1=P0^1;
void mode1();
void reset (void);

void main()
{
    EA=1;
    EX0=1;
    ET0=1;
    EX1=1;

while(1){
    EA=1;
    EX0=1;
    ET0=1;
    EX1=1;
        if(sw1){
            mode1();
        }
        P1=0x01;
    }
}

void ex0() interrupt 0{
    if(!btn){
        //reset();
        Enable_Watchdog(); 
    }
}
/*
void reset (void){
(//(void (code *) (void)) 0x0000) ();
    (void (code *)(void)) 0) ();
}
    */

void mode1(){

    unsigned char repeat1 = 0x80;
    unsigned char repeat0 = 0x01;
    int g=0;
    int i =0;
    int j=0;
    EA=1;
    EX0=1;
    ET0=1;
    EX1=1;
        //how many leds it must go accross minus 1 since repeat 1 and 0

        while(sw1){
        EA=1;
        EX0=1;
        ET0=1;
        EX1=1;
        for(i =0; i <7; i++){
                P1=repeat1 >> i;
                delay();
            }
        for(j=0; j<7; j++){
            P1=repeat0 << j;
            delay();
        }
    }
}


void delay(){
    int k, j;
    for(k=0; k<0xff; k++)
        for(j=0;j<0xff;j++);

}
```

Comment: You should rethink your design, if you want to make an interrupt go back to `main()`... erm... where in `main()`? -- Anyway, if you want to stick to C, you can call an ISR like a standard function to make `RETI` execute. -- Alternatively, in assembler you can push 0x0000 on the stack and then `RETI`. -- A correct solution would set a flag and make the main loop react on that.

Comment: I thought to rethink it as well, but my professor makes it clear to use one of these external interrupts to go back into main and wait for the switch to be on again.

Comment: Beginning of main, based on the project.

Comment: We can't use assembly.

Comment: I would get a clarification of the task/question it doesnt make sense maybe you misread or understood it.  if using C you are using assembly language most likely btw.  they didnt just mean have the interrupt return. or leave a flag to have a function return?

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with the watchdog enable you already have in the code in the question? It will work, but needs soem finessing:

```
void ex0() interrupt 0
{
    if(!btn)
    {
        EA = 0;   // Disable interrupts

        // Set watchdog counter and timeout 
        // to zero for immediate reset
        PCA0L    = 0x00;
        PCA0H    = 0x00;
        PCA0CPL2 = 0x00; 

        // Enable watchdog
        PCA0MD  |= 0x40;

        for(;;);  // Wait for reset
    }
}
```

A better solution if you are able is to connect a GPIO to the reset pin (with a pull-up) and reset it directly.  On reset, the GPIO will tri-state, so release the reset - by virtue of the pull-up. You need to take care when initialising the GPIO that you do not immediately pull it low.  Probably best to leave it as a tri-stated input until you actually want to effect a reset.

Comment: @Tech you are welcome, but I draw your attention to https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment, the bit about when not to comment.  The appropriate way of expressing the usefulness of an answer is to up-vote and/or accept it.  It would also be interesting to know what your work-around was if it differed from this answer.  That would be a valid comment or you could post your own answer if it differs significantly from this.